# Is there any string length limit for JSON.parse()?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this variable in (I believe it's json). And I try to pass it to an object using JSON.parse (), which simply BREAK the execution of the script. I have removed the single quotation marks, considering that the whole chain starts and ends with single quotation marks, but it did not solve the problem.
In this online tool (http://json.parser.online.fr/), the variable converts normally.
Any suggestion of what might be locking this script and preventing the conversion of the variable to object?

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{"settings":{"dates.format":"yyyy-MM-dd","dates.locale":"en_US","social.google.enable":1,"social.twitter.enable":1,"social.facebook.enable":1,"realtime.enable":0,"registration.disable":0,"branding.use_custom_theme":1,"branding.favicon":"favicon.ico","branding.logo_dark":"client\/assets\/images\/logo-dark.png","branding.logo_light":"client\/assets\/images\/logo-light.png","i18n.default_localization":"english","i18n.enable":1,"logging.sentry_public":null,"realtime.pusher_key":null,"billing.enable":0,"billing.paypal_test_mode":1,"billing.stripe_test_mode":1,"billing.stripe.enable":0,"billing.paypal.enable":0,"billing.accepted_cards":"[\"visa\",\"mastercard\",\"american-express\",\"discover\"]","homepage.type":"default","homepage.value":"","cache.report_minutes":"60","cache.homepage_days":1,"automation.artist_interval":"7","artist_provider":"Local","album_provider":"Local","radio_provider":"Spotify","genres_provider":"Local","album_images_provider":"real","artist_images_provider":"real","new_releases_provider":"Local","top_tracks_provider":"Local","top_albums_provider":"Local","search_provider":"Local","audio_search_provider":"local","artist_bio_provider":"wikipedia","youtube.suggested_quality":"default","youtube.region_code":"US","player.default_volume":"30","player.hide_queue":0,"player.hide_video":0,"player.hide_video_button":0,"player.hide_lyrics":0,"player.mobile.auto_open_overlay":1,"player.enable_download":0,"player.sort_method":"external","https.enable_cert_verification":1,"site.force_https":0,"menus":"[{\"name\":\"Primary\",\"position\":\"sidebar-primary\",\"items\":[{\"type\":\"route\",\"order\":1,\"label\":\"Popular Albums\",\"action\":\"popular-albums\",\"icon\":\"album\"},{\"type\":\"route\",\"order\":2,\"label\":\"Popular Genres\",\"action\":\"popular-genres\",\"icon\":\"local-offer\"},{\"type\":\"route\",\"order\":3,\"label\":\"Top 50\",\"action\":\"top-50\",\"icon\":\"trending-up\"},{\"type\":\"route\",\"order\":4,\"label\":\"New Releases\",\"action\":\"new-releases\",\"icon\":\"new-releases\"}]},{\"name\":\"Secondary \",\"position\":\"sidebar-secondary\",\"items\":[{\"type\":\"route\",\"order\":1,\"label\":\"Songs\",\"action\":\"\\\/library\\\/songs\",\"icon\":\"audiotrack\"},{\"type\":\"route\",\"order\":2,\"label\":\"Albums\",\"action\":\"\\\/library\\\/albums\",\"icon\":\"album\"},{\"type\":\"route\",\"order\":3,\"label\":\"Artists\",\"action\":\"\\\/library\\\/artists\",\"icon\":\"mic\"}]},{\"name\":\"Mobile \",\"position\":\"mobile-bottom\",\"items\":[{\"type\":\"route\",\"order\":1,\"label\":\"Genres\",\"action\":\"\\\/popular-genres\",\"icon\":\"local-offer\"},{\"type\":\"route\",\"order\":2,\"label\":\"Top 50\",\"action\":\"\\\/top-50\",\"icon\":\"trending-up\"},{\"type\":\"route\",\"order\":3,\"label\":\"Search\",\"action\":\"\\\/search\",\"icon\":\"search\"},{\"type\":\"route\",\"order\":4,\"label\":\"Your Music\",\"action\":\"\\\/library\",\"icon\":\"library-music\"},{\"type\":\"route\",\"order\":4,\"label\":\"Account\",\"action\":\"\\\/account\\\/settings\",\"icon\":\"person\"}]}]","ads.disable":0,"ads.general_top":"<h1>Aqui Propagandas e Comerciais Para Rentabilizar seu SITE.<\/h1>","ads.general_bottom":"<h2>Aqui Propagandas e Comerciais Para Rentabilizar seu SITE.<\/h2>\n<h3>Aqui Propagandas e Comerciais Para Rentabilizar seu SITE.<\/h3>","billing.stripe_public_key":null,"common.site.demo":false,"branding.site_name":"BeMusic","base_url":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1:9090\/estudio\/temp","version":"2.3.6"},"csrf_token":"aUHW7fN9XnzkS2O866kaKm5SrFeLToGAqadhzs8K","guests_role":{"id":1,"name":"guests","permissions":{"users.view":1,"pages.view":1,"artists.view":1,"albums.view":1,"tracks.view":1,"genres.view":1,"lyrics.view":1,"playlists.view":1},"default":false,"guests":true,"created_at":"2019-04-04 10:15:28","updated_at":"2019-04-04 10:15:28"},"i18n":{"model":{"id":1,"name":"english","created_at":"2019-04-04 10:15:28","updated_at":"2019-04-04 10:15:28"},"lines":{"albums":"albums","Add":"Add","":"","Image":"Image","Name":"Name","Artist":"Artist","Release Date":"Release Date","Popularity":"Popularity","Number of Tracks":"Number of Tracks","Views":"Views","tracks":"tracks","New Track":"New Track","Number":"Number","Artists":"Artists","Duration":"Duration","Nothing To Display.":"Nothing To Display.","No tracks have been attached to this album yet.":"No tracks have been attached to this album yet.","Update":"Update","Create":"Create","Search artists...":"Search artists...","Auto Update":"Auto Update","Yes":"Yes","No":"No","artists":"artists","Number of Albums":"Number of Albums","Page Views":"Page Views","Created At":"Created At","New Album":"New Album","Small Image":"Small Image","Large Image":"Large Image","Genres":"Genres","Add new...":"Add new...","Whether this artist data (bio, discography, images etc.) should be updated periodically.":"Whether this artist data (bio, discography, images etc.) should be updated periodically.","Biography":"Biography","Biography Images":"Biography Images","Separate images with a new line (enter).":"Separate images with a new line (enter).","Update Genre\n        New Genre":"Update Genre\n        New Genre","Update Genre":"Update Genre","New Genre":"New Genre","Upload genre image or enter image url.":"Upload genre image or enter image url.","Close":"Close","Update\n            Create":"Update\n            Create","genres":"genres","Number of Artists":"Number of Artists","Update Lyric\r\n        New Lyric":"Update Lyric\r\n        New Lyric","Update Lyric":"Update Lyric","New Lyric":"New Lyric","Track":"Track","Search tracks...":"Search tracks...","Update\r\n            Create":"Update\r\n            Create","lyrics":"lyrics","Song":"Song","Album":"Album","Last Updated":"Last Updated","playlists":"playlists","Owner":"Owner","Public":"Public","Blocked Artist":"Blocked Artist","Artists that should be blocked on the site (they will not be searchable, indexable, or appear on the site in any other way.":"Artists that should be blocked on the site (they will not be searchable, indexable, or appear on the site in any other way.","+Artist Name":"+Artist Name","Player":"Player","Select streaming method and configure player defaults and interface.":"Select streaming method and configure player defaults and interface.","Streaming Method":"Streaming Method","What method should be used to stream music on the site.":"What method should be used to stream music on the site.","Youtube Api Key":"Youtube Api Key","Suggested Quality":"Suggested Quality","Default":"Default","Small":"Small","Medium":"Medium","Large":"Large","HD720":"HD720","HD1080":"HD1080","Highres":"Highres","What quality should be used for youtube videos.":"What quality should be used for youtube videos.","Youtube Region Code":"Youtube Region Code","For what country should youtube results be returned. US recommended. ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 Code.":"For what country should youtube results be returned. US recommended. ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 Code.","Soundcloud Api Key":"Soundcloud Api Key","Default Player Volume (1 to 100)":"Default Player Volume (1 to 100)","Sort Method":"Sort Method","External Popularity":"External Popularity","Local Views":"Local Views","This will be used to sort artists, albums and tracks across the site.":"This will be used to sort artists, albums and tracks across the site.","Automatically Open Overlay on Mobile":"Automatically Open Overlay on Mobile","Should fullscreen video overlay be opened automatically on mobile when user starts playback.":"Should fullscreen video overlay be opened automatically on mobile when user starts playback.","Enable Download Functionality":"Enable Download Functionality","Only works for custom uploaded tracks.":"Only works for custom uploaded tracks.","Hide Queue":"Hide Queue","Should player queue (right sidebar) be hidden by default.":"Should player queue (right sidebar) be hidden by default.","Hide Video":"Hide Video","Should small video in the bottom right corner be hidden.":"Should small video in the bottom right corner be hidden.","Hide Lyrics Button":"Hide Lyrics Button","Hide \"Lyrics\" button in player controls bar.":"Hide \"Lyrics\" button in player controls bar.","Hide Video Button":"Hide Video Button","Hide video toggle button in player controls bar.":"Hide video toggle button in player controls bar.","Hide Radio Button":"Hide Radio Button","Hide all \"go to radio\" buttons across the site.":"Hide all \"go to radio\" buttons across the site.","Data Providers":"Data Providers","Select and configure providers that will be used to automate the site.":"Select and configure providers that will be used to automate the site.","Information":"Information","Local provider means that only data created manually via admin area will be used. No attempt will be made to fetch it from any 3rd party APIs or sites.":"Local provider means that only data created manually via admin area will be used. No attempt will be made to fetch it from any 3rd party APIs or sites.","Generate Sitemap":"Generate Sitemap","Once generated, sitemap index url will be":"Once generated, sitemap index url will be","Artist Provider":"Artist Provider","Album Provider":"Album Provider","Search Provider":"Search Provider","Genres Provider":"Genres Provider","New Releases Provider":"New Releases Provider","Popular Albums Provider":"Popular Albums Provider","Top 50 Provider":"Top 50 Provider","Artist Biography Provider":"Artist Biography Provider","Wikipedia Language":"Wikipedia Language","ISO 639-1 (two letter) language code.":"ISO 639-1 (two letter) language code.","Spotify ID":"Spotify ID","Spotify Secret":"Spotify Secret","Discogs ID":"Discogs ID","Discogs Secret":"Discogs Secret","Last.fm Api Key":"Last.fm Api Key","Should only be disabled if there are problems with 3rd party data providers.":"Should only be disabled if there are problems with 3rd party data providers.","Update Track\r\n        New Track":"Update Track\r\n        New Track","Update Track":"Update Track","Search albums...":"Search albums...","Duration (ms)":"Duration (ms)","Popularity (1 to 100)":"Popularity (1 to 100)","Youtube ID":"Youtube ID","Soundcloud Url":"Soundcloud Url","Url":"Url","(Optional) Absolute url from where track should be streamed.":"(Optional) Absolute url from where track should be streamed.","Upload":"Upload","Plays":"Plays","Release Date:":"Release Date:","Number of Songs:":"Number of Songs:","Running Time:":"Running Time:","Play":"Play","Pause":"Pause","More...":"More...","Add to Queue":"Add to Queue","Add to Playlist":"Add to Playlist","Save to Your Music":"Save to Your Music","Copy Album Link":"Copy Album Link","Share":"Share","Edit":"Edit","New Releases":"New Releases","No new releases found.":"No new releases found.","Could not find any new releases. Please try again later.":"Could not find any new releases. Please try again later.","Popular Albums":"Popular Albums","No albums found.":"No albums found.","Could not find any popular albums. Please try again later.":"Could not find any popular albums. Please try again later.","Overview":"Overview","Similar Artists":"Similar Artists","About":"About","Popular Songs":"Popular Songs","Show More":"Show More","Show Less":"Show Less","Albums":"Albums","Could not find any similar artists for":"Could not find any similar artists for","Could not find biography for":"Could not find biography for","Go to Artist Radio":"Go to Artist Radio","Copy Artist Link":"Copy Artist Link","Back":"Back","Select":"Select","New Playlist":"New Playlist","Copy":"Copy","via email":"via email","+Email address":"+Email address","(Optional) Email message":"(Optional) Email message","Sharing with:":"Sharing with:","Filter...":"Filter...","Sorted by":"Sorted by","Popular Genres":"Popular Genres","No genres found.":"No genres found.","Could not find any popular genres. Please try again later.":"Could not find any popular genres. Please try again later.","Main site search":"Main site search","Search...":"Search...","Admin Area":"Admin Area","Account Settings":"Account Settings","Logout":"Logout","Login":"Login","Register":"Register","Your Music":"Your Music","Playlists":"Playlists","Lyrics":"Lyrics","Update Playlist":"Update Playlist","Playlist Name":"Playlist Name","Playlist Description":"Playlist Description","Give your playlist a catchy description.":"Give your playlist a catchy description.","Songs":"Songs","By":"By","Follow":"Follow","Unfollow":"Unfollow","Delete":"Delete","Make Public":"Make Public","Make Private":"Make Private","Copy Link":"Copy Link","Go to Track Radio":"Go to Track Radio","Remove from Queue":"Remove from Queue","Remove from Playlist":"Remove from Playlist","Remove from Your Music":"Remove from Your Music","Show Lyrics":"Show Lyrics","Copy Track Link":"Copy Track Link","Download":"Download","Radio":"Radio","Search results for":"Search results for","Top Results":"Top Results","Users":"Users","No results for":"No results for","Please check your spelling or try using different keywords.":"Please check your spelling or try using different keywords.","Search":"Search","Find artists, albums, songs, playlists and more.":"Find artists, albums, songs, playlists and more.","View All Results...":"View All Results...","Followers":"Followers","No results found.":"No results found.","Top 50":"Top 50","No charts found.":"No charts found.","Could not find charts. Please try again later.":"Could not find charts. Please try again later.","Duration:":"Duration:","Featured in":"Featured in","Date Added":"Date Added","Artist Name":"Artist Name","Nothing to display.":"Nothing to display.","You have not added any albums to your library yet.":"You have not added any albums to your library yet.","Number of Songs":"Number of Songs","You have not added any artists to your library yet.":"You have not added any artists to your library yet.","Album Name":"Album Name","You have not added any songs to your library yet.":"You have not added any songs to your library yet.","Public Playlists":"Public Playlists","Following":"Following","Seems like this user has not created any playlists yet.":"Seems like this user has not created any playlists yet.","Seems like this user is not following anyone yet.":"Seems like this user is not following anyone yet.","Seems like no one is following this user yet.":"Seems like no one is following this user yet.","You have already created a playlist with this name.":"You have already created a playlist with this name.","auth.failed":"These credentials do not match our records.","auth.throttle":"Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds.","pagination.previous":"&laquo; Previous","pagination.next":"Next &raquo;","passwords.password":"Passwords must be at least six characters and match the confirmation.","passwords.reset":"Your password has been reset!","passwords.sent":"We have e-mailed your password reset link!","passwords.token":"This password reset token is invalid.","passwords.user":"We cant find a user with that e-mail address.","validation.accepted":"The :attribute must be accepted.","validation.active_url":"The :attribute is not a valid URL.","validation.after":"The :attribute must be a date after :date.","validation.after_or_equal":"The :attribute must be a date after or equal to :date.","validation.alpha":"The :attribute may only contain letters.","validation.alpha_dash":"The :attribute may only contain letters, numbers, and dashes.","validation.alpha_num":"The :attribute may only contain letters and numbers.","validation.array":"The :attribute must be an array.","validation.before":"The :attribute must be a date before :date.","validation.before_or_equal":"The :attribute must be a date before or equal to :date.","validation.between.numeric":"The :attribute must be between :min and :max.","validation.between.file":"The :attribute must be between :min and :max kilobytes.","validation.between.string":"The :attribute must be between :min and :max characters.","validation.between.array":"The :attribute must have between :min and :max items.","validation.boolean":"The :attribute field must be true or false.","validation.confirmed":"The :attribute confirmation does not match.","validation.date":"The :attribute is not a valid date.","validation.date_format":"The :attribute does not match the format :format.","validation.different":"The :attribute and :other must be different.","validation.digits":"The :attribute must be :digits digits.","validation.digits_between":"The :attribute must be between :min and :max digits.","validation.dimensions":"The :attribute has invalid image dimensions.","validation.distinct":"The :attribute field has a duplicate value.","validation.email":"The :attribute must be a valid email address.","validation.exists":"The selected :attribute is invalid.","validation.file":"The :attribute must be a file.","validation.filled":"The :attribute field must have a value.","validation.image":"The :attribute must be an image.","validation.in":"The selected :attribute is invalid.","validation.in_array":"The :attribute field does not exist in :other.","validation.integer":"The :attribute must be an integer.","validation.ip":"The :attribute must be a valid IP address.","validation.ipv4":"The :attribute must be a valid IPv4 address.","validation.ipv6":"The :attribute must be a valid IPv6 address.","validation.json":"The :attribute must be a valid JSON string.","validation.max.numeric":"The :attribute may not be greater than :max.","validation.max.file":"The :attribute may not be greater than :max kilobytes.","validation.max.string":"The :attribute may not be greater than :max characters.","validation.max.array":"The :attribute may not have more than :max items.","validation.mimes":"The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.","validation.mimetypes":"The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.","validation.min.numeric":"The :attribute must be at least :min.","validation.min.file":"The :attribute must be at least :min kilobytes.","validation.min.string":"The :attribute must be at least :min characters.","validation.min.array":"The :attribute must have at least :min items.","validation.not_in":"The selected :attribute is invalid.","validation.numeric":"The :attribute must be a number.","validation.present":"The :attribute field must be present.","validation.regex":"The :attribute format is invalid.","validation.required":"The :attribute field is required.","validation.required_if":"The :attribute field is required when :other is :value.","validation.required_unless":"The :attribute field is required unless :other is in :values.","validation.required_with":"The :attribute field is required when :values is present.","validation.required_with_all":"The :attribute field is required when :values is present.","validation.required_without":"The :attribute field is required when :values is not present.","validation.required_without_all":"The :attribute field is required when none of :values are present.","validation.same":"The :attribute and :other must match.","validation.size.numeric":"The :attribute must be :size.","validation.size.file":"The :attribute must be :size kilobytes.","validation.size.string":"The :attribute must be :size characters.","validation.size.array":"The :attribute must contain :size items.","validation.string":"The :attribute must be a string.","validation.timezone":"The :attribute must be a valid zone.","validation.unique":"The :attribute has already been taken.","validation.uploaded":"The :attribute failed to upload.","validation.url":"The :attribute format is invalid.","These credentials do not match our records.":"These credentials do not match our records.","Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds.":"Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds.","&laquo; Previous":"&laquo; Previous","Next &raquo;":"Next &raquo;","Passwords must be at least six characters and match the confirmation.":"Passwords must be at least six characters and match the confirmation.","Your password has been reset!":"Your password has been reset!","We have e-mailed your password reset link!":"We have e-mailed your password reset link!","This password reset token is invalid.":"This password reset token is invalid.","We cant find a user with that e-mail address.":"We cant find a user with that e-mail address.","The :attribute must be accepted.":"The :attribute must be accepted.","The :attribute is not a valid URL.":"The :attribute is not a valid URL.","The :attribute must be a date after :date.":"The :attribute must be a date after :date.","The :attribute must be a date after or equal to :date.":"The :attribute must be a date after or equal to :date.","The :attribute may only contain letters.":"The :attribute may only contain letters.","The :attribute may only contain letters, numbers, and dashes.":"The :attribute may only contain letters, numbers, and dashes.","The :attribute may only contain letters and numbers.":"The :attribute may only contain letters and numbers.","The :attribute must be an array.":"The :attribute must be an array.","The :attribute must be a date before :date.":"The :attribute must be a date before :date.","The :attribute must be a date before or equal to :date.":"The :attribute must be a date before or equal to :date.","The :attribute must be between :min and :max.":"The :attribute must be between :min and :max.","The :attribute must be between :min and :max kilobytes.":"The :attribute must be between :min and :max kilobytes.","The :attribute must be between :min and :max characters.":"The :attribute must be between :min and :max characters.","The :attribute must have between :min and :max items.":"The :attribute must have between :min and :max items.","The :attribute field must be true or false.":"The :attribute field must be true or false.","The :attribute confirmation does not match.":"The :attribute confirmation does not match.","The :attribute is not a valid date.":"The :attribute is not a valid date.","The :attribute does not match the format :format.":"The :attribute does not match the format :format.","The :attribute and :other must be different.":"The :attribute and :other must be different.","The :attribute must be :digits digits.":"The :attribute must be :digits digits.","The :attribute must be between :min and :max digits.":"The :attribute must be between :min and :max digits.","The :attribute has invalid image dimensions.":"The :attribute has invalid image dimensions.","The :attribute field has a duplicate value.":"The :attribute field has a duplicate value.","The :attribute must be a valid email address.":"The :attribute must be a valid email address.","The selected :attribute is invalid.":"The selected :attribute is invalid.","The :attribute must be a file.":"The :attribute must be a file.","The :attribute field must have a value.":"The :attribute field must have a value.","The :attribute must be an image.":"The :attribute must be an image.","The :attribute field does not exist in :other.":"The :attribute field does not exist in :other.","The :attribute must be an integer.":"The :attribute must be an integer.","The :attribute must be a valid IP address.":"The :attribute must be a valid IP address.","The :attribute must be a valid IPv4 address.":"The :attribute must be a valid IPv4 address.","The :attribute must be a valid IPv6 address.":"The :attribute must be a valid IPv6 address.","The :attribute must be a valid JSON string.":"The :attribute must be a valid JSON string.","The :attribute may not be greater than :max.":"The :attribute may not be greater than :max.","The :attribute may not be greater than :max kilobytes.":"The :attribute may not be greater than :max kilobytes.","The :attribute may not be greater than :max characters.":"The :attribute may not be greater than :max characters.","The :attribute may not have more than :max items.":"The :attribute may not have more than :max items.","The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.":"The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.","The :attribute must be at least :min.":"The :attribute must be at least :min.","The :attribute must be at least :min kilobytes.":"The :attribute must be at least :min kilobytes.","The :attribute must be at least :min characters.":"The :attribute must be at least :min characters.","The :attribute must have at least :min items.":"The :attribute must have at least :min items.","The :attribute must be a number.":"The :attribute must be a number.","The :attribute field must be present.":"The :attribute field must be present.","The :attribute format is invalid.":"The :attribute format is invalid.","The :attribute field is required.":"The :attribute field is required.","The :attribute field is required when :other is :value.":"The :attribute field is required when :other is :value.","The :attribute field is required unless :other is in :values.":"The :attribute field is required unless :other is in :values.","The :attribute field is required when :values is present.":"The :attribute field is required when :values is present.","The :attribute field is required when :values is not present.":"The :attribute field is required when :values is not present.","The :attribute field is required when none of :values are present.":"The :attribute field is required when none of :values are present.","The :attribute and :other must match.":"The :attribute and :other must match.","The :attribute must be :size.":"The :attribute must be :size.","The :attribute must be :size kilobytes.":"The :attribute must be :size kilobytes.","The :attribute must be :size characters.":"The :attribute must be :size characters.","The :attribute must contain :size items.":"The :attribute must contain :size items.","The :attribute must be a string.":"The :attribute must be a string.","The :attribute must be a valid zone.":"The :attribute must be a valid zone.","The :attribute has already been taken.":"The :attribute has already been taken.","The :attribute failed to upload.":"The :attribute failed to upload.","The :attribute is not correct.":"The :attribute is not correct."}},"user":{"id":1,"username":"Marco Andre","first_name":null,"last_name":null,"avatar_url":null,"gender":null,"permissions":{"admin":1,"superAdmin":1},"email":"professormarco@msn.com","card_brand":null,"card_last_four":null,"created_at":"2019-04-04 10:15:27","updated_at":"2019-04-04 11:38:18","confirmed":1,"confirmation_code":null,"language":"english","country":null,"timezone":null,"avatar":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1:9090\/estudio\/temp\/storage\/avatars\/gKeugKkYPvke8FeIlGt0eVywxpwLuaJNlc0Mhipb.png","stripe_id":null,"available_space":null,"followers_count":0,"display_name":"professormarco","has_password":true,"roles":[],"followed_users":[]},"tracks":[2],"playlists":[]}');
alert(obj.settings.dates.format);
```

Comment: Why not just put the JSON directly in the JavaScript as an object initializer?

Comment: "*simply BREAK the execution of the script*" is not useful. What's the actual error?

Comment: On my Blade with 16 GB of RAM, it's slow even to enable edit mode on this question. Your string is large, yes (~27 k characters), but why are you parsing JSON in this way? Is this just an example, or do you actually receive this data from a REST call? I looked at the JSON and it's full of inline errors, too, like `The :attribute must be :size characters.":"The :attribute must be :size characters` _in the JSON string itself_. Please review it.

Comment: The real error is that it does not convert. If you run this script you will see that "ALERT" does not even happen.

Comment: I get this variable like that and I need to treat it.

Comment: So what is the error message?

Comment: @Eibo-SistemasWeb Your JSON is malformed: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 636 of the JSON data`. If this is _the exact string you receive from a third party_ (which seems to be what you're saying), then _they_ need to fix it for you. If _you_ have created this JSON string, look at how you are creating it and update your question, because that is where your problem is.

Comment: How can you see this debugging message, is it through a browser or some specific program?

Comment: Also, please see https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/. You didn't include the exception thrown in the DevTools console, which either means you didn't know we would find it useful to read (mais si!), or you didn't know there was a console in which you could see it (a bigger problem). In most browsers: `F12` and look for "Console". It's largely similar in FireFox.

Comment: @Eibo-SistemasWeb It's in the browser console. How do you debug your JavaScript if you don't know about the console?

Comment: Not your which is the ideal browser for this. Mine is Chromium (Chrome for Linux). And the only debugging information it provides is: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token v".

Comment: @Eibo-SistemasWeb : Open Chrome. Press SHIFT-CTRL-i     You will see a window opening up on the right side of the screen. Probably with some pink error messages that you can ignore. Then you can type things to be interpreted, such as   a = 2 + 2    and you will get the answer. You can paste the "var obj = ..." line into that window.

Comment: @Eibo-SistemasWeb I find that unlikely. There isn't even a `v` token in your code. I've converted it into a runnable snippet; click *Run code snippet* and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two separate problems (after @melpomene below pointed out I missed the first one!):

## The line beginning "var obj = " is malformed.

Please verify this by pasting it into (for example) Visual Studio Code, and saving the file as "test.js", for example.

## You are accessing the properties of obj incorrectly.

Here is an explanation using a somewhat simpler example JSON text.

#### Object property keys may contain "." in Javascript

You are not creating the heirarchy you *think* you are creating  8-)

You *think* you are putting something in the `c` child of the `b` child of `a`, but actually you are putting something in the `b.c` child of `a`.

Look at this:

```
a={"b.c":10}

console.log(a)
Result ->       {b.c: 10}

a.b.c
Result ->       * Error * cannot read property 'c' of undefined
```

There is no such thing as `a.b`, so you can't read property `c` of it.

Instead you have to read it as follows:

```
a["b.c"]
Result ->       10
```

#### JSON doesn't allow you to set children in the manner you are trying

The limit you are hitting is not a length limit, but of expressivity. You can't directly set a property `dates` and its child `format` in this way:

```
{ "settings": { "dates.format": "xxx" }}
```

Either restructure the JSON text as follows:

> { "settings": { "dates": { "format": "yyyy-MM-dd", "locale": "en_US" ..... }}}

Or, if that would be too much work, and you are entirely in control of the software that reads from `obj`, you could keep the JSON the same and instead make a special point of reading the items as here:

> alert (obj.settings["dates.format"])

or even, to make it more obvious to your future self when reading, use the `[""]` notation consistently throughout. This is the format used in Python, and works in Javascript too:

> alert ( obj["settings"]["dates.format"] )

Comment: That's only half of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
let obj = {
    name: "Mark",
    surname: "Minerov"
};

let object = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(object); // {"name":"Mark","surname":"Minerov"}

let parsedObject = JSON.parse(object);
console.log(parsedObject);  //normal object
```

Try it, i think it will help you.